# VC6 Refactoring Nested Class

Tags: c++, refactoring, nested-class, visual-c++-6

I'm looking for suggestions on refactoring a legacy code class.

I have a class that has lots and lots of nested classes. The trick here is they are in a private section of the class, meaning only the outer class can create that object.

My initial thought was to pull those classes out and put them in separate header files, and make the constructor private, and let the outer class be a friend class. But then I quickly realized that, that (former)outer class would have access to that (former)nested classes private variables/methods. This I think is worse than risking others creating that (former)nested class.

Is there a better way to do this? **Is there a best practices answer?**

More than anything I want to get these HUGE nested classes moved into different files.

Maybe the better question should be. **Is it wrong to want to change this??**

I think keeping them tied together makes them harder to evenually unit test, though, I guess I could use `friend` keyword, to get around this issue.

Comment: It is reasonably common to define helper classes in a namespace named, say, `internal`, and then just have a gentlemen's agreement that only the implementation of module X is allowed to touch anything in X::internal.

Comment: Well these classes go beyond helper classes, they really are the core of system. The thought almost seemed to have one outer class, that wrapped core classes. Very few people work on this code too (me and one other, occasionally). I'm really trying to make it easier for me, but at the same time add value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this thing dosen't even have namespaces.

Comment: By "helper classes" I didn't mean "insignificant classes of little value", but more like "classes that are not part of the public API of module X". It doesn't matter how important they are to the implementation, just that they are not part of the external interface (which they clearly aren't, or they couldn't be private to begin with).

Comment: What's stopping you from adding some?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've thought about it, maybe as a step 2. Idk, I keeping thing I'm going to get frowned upon for trying to make too many unnecessary changes to a product that we are trying to kill. Though this product is like our Windows XP, its not going to die so easily.